# MongoDB Unable to reach primary for set '<new replica set name>'

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to rename a MondoDB Replica Set as explained in the MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/rename-unsharded-replica-set/):

```
/* Set `newId` to the new replica set name */
var newId = 'idcom'

var doc = db.getSiblingDB("local").system.replset.findOne()
var oldId = doc._id
doc._id = newId
db.getSiblingDB("local").system.replset.save(doc)
db.getSiblingDB("local").system.replset.remove({_id: oldId})
```

However, it did not work and I am unable to revert to the previous configuration. If I attempt to repeat the instructions (start with a different port, etc.) the mongod.service on my Ubuntu machine, it does not start due to the following error:

```
mongod[20493]: Unrecognized option: processManagement.replication.replSetName 
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT 
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If I attempt starting MongoDB via *mongod* command
**mongod --dbpath /opt/mongodb/ --port 27017 --replSet idcom** the server starts, but I cannot access the MongoDB terminal and logs keep throwing the following:

```
NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set idcomm
```

Any help on how to revert to the previous configuration, please? Previously the SECONDARY was set with **replSetName: "comm0"**

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to deploy the replicaset from scratch.

1. Stop all instances
2. Restart one instance in maintenance mode as described in
   [Restart the secondary as a standalone on a different port](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/#restart-the-secondary-as-a-standalone-on-a-different-port)
3. Connect to this instance and drop the `local` database: `db.getSiblingDB('local').drop()`
4. On all **other** nodes remove all files from `dbpath` (maybe you can skip this, because an [Initial Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/replica-set-sync/index.html) will delete all data anyway)
5. Restart the instance in normal mode and deploy the replicaset as given in [Deploy a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/), i.e. `rs.initiate(), rs.add(), etc.`

Comment: I did work. Thanks for your help!